# Focus method not working for lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a LWC that is deployed to production and working fine. The LWC contains only a lightning-input component and some JS. The LWC is used on a screen flow. The main purpose of the LWC is to automatically focus the input field when the page loads. The field is focused so that a USB scanner can 'write' to the field automatically.

The LWC works properly in Spring '21 - when the page loads the input field is focused.
We tried this in Summer '21 and the field does not focus. I don't see any JS errors in the dev console.

I created a trivial LWC and flow to confirm I could reproduce the issue.

Did I miss a functionality change in the release notes or is something else wrong?

###### eotest.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-input onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

###### eotest.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';

export default class eotest extends LightningElement {

    @track _txtScannedValue = '';
    @api 
    get txtScannedValue(){
        return this._txtScannedValue;
    }

    handleChange(event) { 
        this._txtScannedValue = event.target.value; 
        const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('txtScannedValue', this._txtScannedValue);
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
    }

    //Focus the scanner textbox when the screen loads
    renderedCallback() {
        const inputBox = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        inputBox.focus();
    }
}
```

###### Test Flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <interviewLabel>_EOTEST {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>_EOTEST</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>CanvasMode</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>AUTO_LAYOUT_CANVAS</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <screens>
        <name>dasfsdfaadsfdsfa</name>
        <label>dasfsdfa</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>158</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <allowPause>true</allowPause>
        <fields>
            <name>asdfdsads</name>
            <dataType>Boolean</dataType>
            <fieldType>InputField</fieldType>
            <isRequired>true</isRequired>
        </fields>
        <fields>
            <name>asdfasdf</name>
            <extensionName>c:eotest</extensionName>
            <fieldType>ComponentInstance</fieldType>
            <inputsOnNextNavToAssocScrn>UseStoredValues</inputsOnNextNavToAssocScrn>
            <isRequired>true</isRequired>
            <storeOutputAutomatically>true</storeOutputAutomatically>
        </fields>
        <showFooter>true</showFooter>
        <showHeader>true</showHeader>
    </screens>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>0</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>dasfsdfaadsfdsfa</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Active</status>
</Flow>
```

Comment: I don't believe any org is on winter 21 anymore! Eveything is on Spring and next version is Summer 22? Can you confirm the versions

Comment: Did you check if `inputBox` is coming as empty or null?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava sorry, yes the difference is between Spring '21 and Summer '21

Comment: Could you fix the question then? If it is a bug then we can bring this to attention to product teams to see what’s going on!

Comment: @ShagunSharma when I alert the value of the 'inputBox' I get "SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }"
So it's not null or blank, it just doesn't seem to focus the field.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava question has been updated

Comment: @Eric what is the behaviour with regular input tag, just to narrow the root cause of the issue!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava what do you mean 'the behaviour with the regular input tag'?

Comment: meaning just use <input> instead of the lightning-input. The base components team wanted me to narrow but i am heads on busy so if you could help testing with just input tag!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava same thing. In our Spring '21 instance the input field focuses. In the Summer '21 instance nothing is focused.
This is what is returned from an alert on the 'query selector': "SecureElement: [object HTMLInputElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }"

Comment: Thank you! Will open an investigation with the respective teams at Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around that works for us in this case.

If you make the input field the first field on the screen AND the 'Show Header' property is set to true for the screen AND there is no 'inline help' icon the textbox will automatically focus.